# Possible to update validator keys for ETH on Allnodes?

Tags: staking, validators

i used https://github.com/ethereum/staking-deposit-cli to generate validator keys. i realized i wasnt offline when i generated them.My validator node on Allnodes is still pending. Just for peace of mind, what is the process to run the validator using new offline created validator keys? Can i update current, somehow?

Answer (score 1):

AllNodes is a private commercial service. Please ask the question from AllNodes support.

This is a public discussion forum about Ethereum and no one here can provide support for AllNodes here.